# Maximized window of Notepad++ overflows onto second display

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, notepad++, laptop-display

I am using an external monitor with my laptop. When I am maximizing notepad++ on laptop, the window of notepad++ overflows to the other display.

[image]

It is hard to show the pixels that overflow. You can understand the width of these pixels at the top side of this image.
Left one is my laptop screen with maximized notepad++.
Right one is my external monitor with Firefox at the background. The YouTube icon is shown because the first tab is YouTube. Notepad++ is the chosen window.

As you can see, **the toolbar and the menu bar do not overflow, only the editor part** overflows onto the other display.

The width of overflowed pixels is really narrow and can be ignored. However, this situation can be very annoying especially when there is a window with dark background on my external monitor.

Debug info of notepad++:

- Notepad++ v7.8.5   (32-bit)
- Build time : Mar  4 2020 - 11:04:20
- Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
- Admin mode : OFF
- Local Conf mode : OFF
- OS Name : Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit)
- OS Version : 1909 OS Build : 18363.778
- Plugins : mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll

Resolutions of both displays are 1920x1080 with 100% scale.
Laptop is 15.6 inches and external monitor is 21.5 inches.
GPU: GeForce GTX 1050

Comment: I had noticed that before and what worked for me is the Monitor **Auto Adjust** feature. Go to your monitor's settings and look for **Auto Adjust**. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I am still not sure what solves the problem, the following ones are possible solutions.

1. Settings > System > Display > Advanced scaling systems . Turn on "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry"
2. Nvidia Control Panel > Display > Adjust desktop size . Choose "Aspect ratio" or "Full-screen" as scaling mode, do not choose the "No scaling".
3. As Gifcrazy commented, **Auto Adjust** setting can be another solution. Unfortunately, my monitor does not have this option.

Additionally, I had used my taskbar at the left side of the screen. Now, my taskbar is located at the bottom. Changing the location of the taskbar may also resolve the problem although it does not seem like a solution.