# Why isn't my second LCD monitor maximizing perfectly?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

My Display 2 is an old LCD monitor, Samsung SyncMaster 913V. [This website](https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-syncmaster-913v-lcd-monitor-19-series) lists its "Native Resolution" as 1280 x 1024. It fails to maximize programs perfectly. You can see below this problem with Notepad and Paint. I see that the 913V recommends 1024 x 768, but this makes everything look too big, so I picked 1920 x 1080.

https://superuser.com/a/1542311 didn't solve my problem, which doesn't happen on my Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 laptop, my Display 1.
[image: screen images]

[image: screen images]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Look for an "auto" or an "adjust" button on your monitor. Make sure you have a full screen image or maximised window open before pressing it. You might need to look in your monitor on screen display settings or it may have a physical button.

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what "Display 2" actually IS, we could REALLY HELP YOU.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You're correct! Sorry! Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old, though excellent monitor.
And You're using it incorrectly. Every day you exceed native resolution you are damaging it. Maybe just a smidge, maybe not.
LCDs should not work at resolutions exceeding it's native due to reasons above and with results exactly like You're complaining about. Technical response is: monitor fails to properly sync at that resolution. Newer monitors would simply blank the screen in that situation to avoid damage to internal circuitry.

There's nothing that can be done about them short of using virtual desktop (emulation of resolution higher than native, and it will be scrolling it when you move mouse to the edge).

if you want higher res than this SyncMaster's native you should buy newer monitor.

Comment: "look for drivers for that LCD" .. if the LCD isn't detected, there won't be any "drivers" for it.  Monitors don't actually have "drivers".. just an .inf file that shows supported display resolutions and refresh rates.  The work is done on the side of the video card.  If you KNOW what the monitor should be supporting you can force it with advanced adapter settings.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - what is a driver if not an .inf file? My point is newer monitors communicate with OS and send back that list of available resolutions. But that's nit the case with older monitors. They need that inf file - driver - for the OS to know what  settings to use.

Comment: I have written over 180 windows device drivers.  An inf file is NOT a driver.  A driver is a binary file that lives within the kernel (usually).. with the exception of a user mode driver which does not (but isn't REALLY a driver).. The OS knowing what setting to use... means (another) DRIVER knows what settings to use.  Your point is valid.. but it isn't a driver.  Sorry.. I am a semantics geek.  I didn't mark you down because your post was a good one.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Problem isn't semantics - it's terminology. I agree with you that there are differences between driver and inf file containing some description. But both will be called drivers and if you search for them you'll get both. Common language is key to communication, even if imperfect.

Comment: "From what you posted I assume you're using older LCD display as Display 2, correct?" Yes. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @TrailingStop See my edited answer.

Comment: “Every day you exceed native resolution you are damaging it.” – Absolutely not! The resolution _never_ arrives at the panel itself, only at the display’s controller. It will either handle higher resolutions correctly if it can or display a “signal out of range” error. It will _not_ physically damage the panel.

Comment: @DanielB - I said *Monitor*, not *panel*. If you set a monitor to display resolution outside the range - and for monitor with native res 1280x1024 to be outputting 1920x1080@60Hz setting can't be good - you are forcing it to work outside safe parameters. Panel may handle it, but internal electronics are working overtime. What happens is not unlike extreme overclocking.

Comment: @DanielB Don't hesitate to write another answer. Always happy to see more opinions.